# Is there a way to define parametrized variables with DUP in x86 assembly?

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, macros, x86

Using x86 assembly, I need to define an array filled with incrementing values. Currently, I define it as an empty array and fill it at runtime by looping through it and setting a value I increment on each step. This looks something like this;

```
myArray DB 10 DUP (0)
...
xor ax, ax
xor bx, bx
mov cx, 10
initArray:
  mov myArray[bx], ax
  inc bx
  add ax, 43
loop initArray
```

The increment value and the size of the array are both known before runtime, so I could do it by defining the values directly in the code, like this...

```
myArray DB 0, 43, 86, 129, ...
```

...but that would take a while, especially with long arrays.

Now for the question; I was wondering if there's a way to create such an array in assembly, like parametrized macros in C? An equivalent to "#define myArray(x) (x*43)" if you will.

Comment: What assembler are you using? MASM, NASM, TASM, etc.

Comment: Ah right, forgot to mention this. I'm using TASM 4.1.

Comment: Well, seeing as you already wrote the code, I'd just look into the TASM specs for macros and turn it into one.

Answer (score 0):

I think your pattern is too advanced to be supported by preprocessors. Why not just write a script that generates it and include it in your build process? You can use TASM's include macros to include it.